# Laravel form submits/POST requests not working

Tags: php, laravel

I've just grabbed our Laravel app from our repo, done `composer update --no-scripts`, run the `artisan...` commands to refresh the database and clear the cache, as per normal.

I come to log in. Nothing happens.

It's as if the form isn't submitting. I can see the POST being sent, there's a `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="xxxxxx">` in the form. But...Nothing. The network tab in chrome tells me there's a 301. If I break the database connection string in **.env** to something invalid, there's no error. Presumably because it's not hitting the server at all.

I've checked with `php artisan route:list` and the all the expected routes are there, including `login`

```
|        | POST     | login                           |                              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@store          | web          |
|        |          |                                 |                              |                                                                         | guest        |
```

I can't fathom what I've missed. Any pointers, please :)

Comment: does that input field inside blade looks likes  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

Comment: It's in the blade as just @csrf

Comment: Also, the same code works on live.

Comment: 301 is a redirect, where is it trying to redirect you to?

Comment: Back to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the server wasn't properly configured for `https`.

I noticed that the `<form action` was http:// rather than https:// and so none of the app's forms were submitting, including login.

Fixing the server config meant that Laravel inserted the right protocol into the form actions, and everything was jolly.

Hope this saves someone else the few hours I wasted trying to debug this badboy.